# Accessing an integer outside its for loop

Tags: java, int

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
  System.out.println("Number: " + x);
}
System.out.println("Done! Counted to: " + x);
```

This gives an error, suggesting to me that I can't access the variable outside the `for` loop.
Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Declare it outside the for then. `int x;
  for (x=1; x<=3; x++) {
   System.out.println("Number: " +x);
  }
  System.out.println("Done! Counted to: "+x);`

Comment: If one of the answers below is correct, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `x` outside loop and use other variable for loop.

### Code

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    System.out.println("Number: " + i);
    x = i;
}
System.out.println("Done! Counted to: " + x);
```

### Result

```
Number: 1
Number: 2
Number: 3
Done! Counted to: 3
```

Comment: crush's answer is marginally more efficient so gets the upvote :)

Comment: @TimB What's more efficient about it?

Comment: He had two variable assignments compared to 1. Compiler would probably optimized that out.

Comment: My solution count to 3 :)

Comment: @MariuszS instead of creating another int, why not add + 1 when printing, and start at 0, or - 1 at the end when printing.

Comment: crush, we shouldnt think what JIT will do, this is his job to optimze this code.

Comment: Totally forgot this was even `Java` it's so trivial.

Comment: There are definitely situations where this kind of approach could be considered more clean. Hard to make judgments about cleanliness on such a trivial example.

Comment: Goodness no, I wouldn't do it like this. While this is a trivial example and it's easy to see what's going on in either case, this would add some readability complexity for no reason (there's an additional variable that you have to follow). But the performance difference is really too minor to care about.

Answer (score 11):

Declare it outside of the `for` statement, then omit the first part of the `for` statement.

```
int x = 1;
for (; x <= 3; x++) {
    System.out.println("Number: " + x);
}

System.out.println("Done! Counted to: " + x);
```

*Hint*: You can omit any of the three parts of the `for` loop. For example, you might wish to omit the last part if you wish to do some conditional incrementing inside of the compound statement that makes up your `for` loop.

```
int x = 1;
for (; x <= 3;) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        x += 2;
    } else {
        x++;
    }
}
```

Becareful with this kind of thing though. It's easy to find yourself in an infinite loop if you aren't careful.

Comment: Note that this will print "Done! Counted to: 4"

Comment: @crush That doesn't matter either. The side effect (`x++`) will always happen one last time before it causes the condition to fail. With this in mind it should probably just print `x - 1`.

Comment: Yeah I'm all over the place right now. I said the same thing on MariuszS's answer...

Comment: You can do that, but this is ugly like hell :)

Comment: To count to 3  with just the loop you'd have to move the break condition to the middle of the loop: `int x = 1; for(;;) { System.out.println(x); if(x < 3) x++; else break; }` Or put the extra increment at the beginning: `int x = 0; while(x < 3) { x++; System.out.println(x); }`

Comment: The OP never said what "Counted to: " should output :D

Comment: Indeed. Especially since in most cases what you actually wanted to know was at what point you broke the loop. After all knowing what the limit of the loop was is trivial as you had it in the conditional of the for loop so this question really only has meaning if you have a break inside the loop (which I know the question doesn't but :s).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, very easily. Just do it like this:

```
int x = 0;
for (x=1; x<=3; x++) {
    System.out.println("Number: " +x);
}

System.out.println("Done! Counted to: "+x);
```

You don't *have* to declare a new variable in the loop, you can use an existing one if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable inside for loop, the scope of that variable is only within a loop.

In order to access that variable outside for loop, declare it outside.

```
int x =0;
for (x=1; x<=3; x++) {
    System.out.println("Number: " +x);
    }
    System.out.println("Done! Counted to: "+x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first part is useless, might as well use a while loop then.

```
int x = 1;

while (x <= 3)  
{         
    System.out.println("Number: " + x);        
    x++;   
}  

System.out.println("Done! Counted to: "+ x);
```

Comment: No, because a for loop makes it much easier to read the code and understand what it's doing. The for loop is the correct construct for this whether the first part of the for is used or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
 
int x=1;
for (; x<=3; x++) {
  System.out.println("Number: " +x);
}
System.out.println("Done! Counted to: "+x);
```